# Mysql query not inserting data into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, insert

I'm trying to create a website that connects to a database. My Select statements work to dispay the data, but neither my insert nor my delete statements actually change the data. I've searched around google and stackoverflow, and attempted to try various "answers" when I got stumped, but it's still not working. As a result, the currect state of my code is a hodgepodge of probably redundant code. I'm fairly new to html and php in general, so I would appreciate the help. I also apologize if my formatting is wrong, as I've never used anything like stackoverflow before. Here is a version of the webpage, for those who won't to see the issue in action. EDIT: Fixed. Everyone's comments and answers helped, but it turned out that I had an if statement checking to make sure the input was only letters, when the first two variables posted contained numbers.

if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])) was the culprit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <form method="post" action="DBADELETE.php?go" id="deleteform">
       <input name="GMOVIE" type="text" placeholder="GMOVIEID of a movie to    delete" required="">
    <input name="UMOVIE" type="text" placeholder="UMOVIEID of a movie to delete" required="">
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="DELETE">            
        </form>
    </div>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="DBAUPDATE.php?go" id="updateform">
       <input name="GMOVIE" type="text" placeholder="GMOVIEID of a movie to update" required="">
    <input name="UMOVIE" type="text" placeholder="UMOVIEID of a movie to update" required="">
<input name="TITLE" type="text" placeholder="TITLE of a movie to update" required="">
<input name="GENRE" type="text" placeholder="GENRE of a movie to update" required="">
<input name="RATING" type="text" placeholder="RATING of a movie to update" required="">
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE">            
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "content1" align = "center">
    <table id = "MOVIES">
    <tr>
        <th>GMOVIEID</th>
        <th>UMOVIEID</th>
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>GENRE</th>
        <th>RATING</th>
    </tr>
<?php
include 'bd.php';
$conn = new mysqli( $host, $user, $pw, $bd_name); 

if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$gmovie=$_POST['GMOVIE'];
$umovie=$_POST['UMOVIE'];
$title=$_POST['TITLE'];
$genre=$_POST['GENRE'];
$rating=$_POST['RATING'];
$gmov_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($gmovie,$conn);
$umov_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($umov,$conn);
$title_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($title,$conn);
$genre_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($genre,$conn);
$rating_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($rating,$conn);  
$q ="INSERT INTO MOVIE (GMOVIEID, UMOVIEID, TITLE,GENRE, RATING)      VALUES($gmovie,$umovie,'$title_safe','$genre_safe','$rating_safe')"
$conn->query($q);

if ($conn->query($q) === TRUE) 
{
echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else 
{
echo "Error: " . $q . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
?>
<?php
include 'bd.php';
$conn = new mysqli( $host, $user, $pw, $bd_name); 

if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}
$q = "SELECT GMOVIEID, UMOVIEID, TITLE, GENRE, RATING FROM MOVIE";
$result = $conn->query( $q );

$row_count = $result->num_rows;

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    if ( ( $row_count % 2 ) == 1 ) {
        echo "<tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row[GMOVIEID] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row[UMOVIEID] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row[TITLE] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row[GENRE] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row[RATING] . "</td>" .
        "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;

    $row_count--;
  }
?>
 </body>
<?php $conn->close(); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: classic mysql api mixing with parse error

Comment: Not to sound stupid, but what does that mean?

Comment: First thing I see that might be the issue is this: if(isset($_GET['go'])){ .  This is a POST request so $_GET won't be set, which won't fire anything else in that condition.

Comment: I changed the mysql to mysqli, took out the GET['go], and now checked a few other parse errors. Now I'm getting an unexpected end of file error

Comment: Added a link to a version of the website to showcase the issue.

Comment: @ y r u using <<<_END_OF_SQL ? No need for that. Just assign the string to $q

Comment: Is this line actually like this in your code? $q =<<<END_OF_SQL
"INSERT INTO MOVIE (GMOVIEID, UMOVIEID, TITLE,GENRE, RATING)      VALUES($gmovie,$umovie,'$title_safe','$genre_safe','$rating_safe')"
END_OF_SQL;  It looks like the <<<END_OF_SQL and END_OF_SQL should be removed.

Comment: Removed that. Now my code is pretty much back to the point that it was before I started trying solution from the internet to get my statements to insert into my database. It's still not doing it though. Here's a link to the current version of the site. movie-rental.000webhostapp.com/DBAMOVIES.php

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to be that the form is rerouting to another page on submit:

```
action="DBAUPDATE.php?go"
```

or

```
action="DBADELETE.php?go"
```

but the insert statement along with boilerplate code is in current page: DBAMOVIES.php

you need to add the insert statements and the boilerplate code in DBAUPDATE.php and DBADELETE.php.

Just create the above two pages and add following statement:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <?php include("DBAMOVIES.php"); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```